# Mojolicious dynamic route action depending on state

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am using Mojolicious::Plugin::Authentication to handle authentication in my app. I am trying to set up a route for slash '/' that will have one controller/action if authenticated, and another if not (i.e., you go to a different page depending on whether you're authenticated.) I'm not sure how to go about achieving this. Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
$r->any('/')->to(cb => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    if ( $self->is_user_authenticated ) {
      $self->redirect_to('member#index');
    }
    else {
      $self->redirect_to('guest#index');
    }
});
```

And...

```
my $logged_in = $r->under (sub {
    my $self = shift;

    if (!$self->session("username")) {
        return undef;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
});

if ( $logged_in ) {
    $logged_in->get('/')-to(controller => 'Member', action => 'index');
}
else {    
    $r->get('/')->to(controller => 'Guest', action => 'index');
}
```

I don't have to use Mojolicious::Plugin::Authentication. I could easily set a session token and check for it myself. Either way, the problem remains: how do I create a dynamic action for a given route?

**Addendum**

Forgot to add, I also tried this:

```
my $auth = $r->under('/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    # Authenticated
    return 1 if $self->is_user_authenticated;

    # Not authenticated
    return undef;
});

$auth->get('/')->to('member#index');

# Routes related to non-members
$r->get('/')->to('guest#index');
```

**Adding Another Detail**

I just wanted to add, I can render or redirect_to something different based on state, e.g.,

```
$r->any('/')->to(cb => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    if ( $self->is_user_authenticated ) {
      $self->render('member/index');
    }
    else {
      $self->render('guest/login');
    }
});
```

And that does work pretty well. However, I am still curious if it's possible to have different controllers/actions for a given route based on the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mojo hooks are what you are looking for, a very powerful feature, particularly useful for authentication:

http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious#HOOKS

You probably need to look at before_dispatch()

Hope this helps.